# How does one validate the Chrome AppCache Origin Trial is working?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-appcache

Working on using the AppCache Origin Trial to extend our support for AppCache for several apps. Following this guide: https://web.dev/appcache-removal/ (which recommends to ask any questions here).

I have Chrome 84 BETA (which is the 1st version to support this AppCache Origin Trial) and would like to validate it is working. This version of Chrome also supports a feature flag to test AppCache removal (https://web.dev/appcache-removal/#testing-prior-to-removal). I had assumed that this flag would not only allow for the simulation of AppCache removal, but would also serve as a test of the AppCache Origin Trial. However, that does NOT seem to be the case. Even if I have a valid AppCache Origin Trial token, if this flag is set AppCache does not work. I suspect this flag is NOT intended for testing the AppCache Origin Trial, but mainly on how apps would behave after the removal (very useful but a different case).

In reading the above page carefully, it seems to indicate the way to test AppCache removal is (https://web.dev/appcache-removal/#origin-trial-deployment-timing-and-logistics): "*Once you've added a token to your AppCache manifest, visit chrome://appcache-internals to confirm that your local instance of Chrome (version 84 or later) has properly associated the origin trial token with your manifest's cached entries. If your origin trial is recognized, you should see a field with Token Expires: Tue Apr 06 2021... on that page, associated with your manifest:*"

So is that it? Just seeing "Token Expires: Tue April 06 2021" under chrome://appcache-internals means it's working? This doesn't feel like a valid test. Is there no way to actually test it functions?

I understand once we have access to Chrome 85 BETA it will allow for a real test: without the token offline won't work, but with the token it should. But that is not available until July 23rd (https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule). We would like to start rolling out the token ahead of time (and make sure its done properly).

So in summary is there any way to test this ahead of Chrome 85 BETA? Is the token expiration showing up it? And lastly, if there is a better place to post this question (since it seems like a question for google) please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the message on the AppCache internals page is sufficient to confirm that the trial is active. If you wanted to test before the feature reaches Beta, you should be able to use the Canary channel.